# How to calculate time constant for RC circuit with more than one resistor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image: The question]

The time constant in the solution is 0.5. (-2t implies tau = 0.5)
I am wondering how they got this.

tau = RC

So I am wondering how to calculate the Rth. The capacitor is inbetween the two resistors in series, so would the Rth be

Rth = 6/(6+2)

But then tau = (6/8)*(1/3) = 0.25

if Rth is not calculated like this and is just = (6+2)

tau = 8*(1/3) which is not equal to 0.5

if Rth is also not calculated like this and is 2/(6+2)

tau = (2/8)*(1/3) which is not equal to 0.5

I know that I can get the Rth from the solution
ie. since the solution says tau = 0.5, then the Rth must be 1.5ohms (since 1.5 * (1/3) = 0.5)

But I cannot see how the resistance at the terminals of the resistor is equivalent to 1.5ohms.

So my question is how to calculate Rth and how to calculate tau.

Comment: Do you know the Thevenin's theory? What is the resistance seen from capacitor terminal ?

Answer (score 1):

2 ohm and 6 ohm are in parallel. So the net resistance as seen by the capacitor(or thevenin's resistance) is 12/8 Ohm

Comment: Thanks yes this is where I went wrong, the arrangement of the resistors didn't look like they were in parallel but I can see why they are now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get Rth is to find V open circuit and I short circuit at the capacitor terminals.  Voc/Isc = Rth.  After you have done this a few times, Rth will be obvious to you.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the two sources (and their respective resistors) into one source. Easy way is to convert to two current sources: -

1. 10 volt and 2 ohms converts to 5 amp in parallel with 2 ohms
2. 5 volt and 6 ohms converts to 0.83333 amps in parallel with 6 ohms

Next combine the two current sources into one at 5.83333 amps with a single resistor of 1.5 ohms in parallel. If you need to convert back to a single voltage source this becomes 8.75 volts sourced from 1.5 ohms.

Hence the time constant is 1.5 x 1/3 = 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple method:

Assume that the capacitor is charged and ask: What is the resistor combination for the discharge process (voltage sources set to zero)? In the case under discussion it is easy to see that both resistors act in parallel.

Comment: I've never thought of it that way, but this is a very intuitive, and interesting approach. Nice! Good to get slapped like that, once in a while.